# how to get maximum camera resolutions in kivy uix camera?

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to get the maximum possible resolution for the camera on the operating android device. How to achieve this with kivy uix camera?

How to even get the list of all possible resolutions?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built in API for this, and in general the kivy.uix.camera is not in a good state on Android.

You *can* do this in general, e.g. as in [this app](https://github.com/inclement/colour-blind-camera), and you could copy that code if you want. Essentially it comes down to using pyjnius to call the relevant parts of the android api.

It's probably possible to use pyjnius to get the supported resolutions before setting the resolution of the kivy camera, this may be an immediate solution for you.